# How to apply custom theme on android document provider?

Tags: android, image-gallery, document-provider, custom-theme

I am opening builtin image provider in android and its opening correctly.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
    // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
    // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
    // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
    // it would be "*/*".
    intent.setType("image/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
```

[image: I want icon]

Now my question is I want to open it with my custom theme.

Such as applying my `android:colorPrimary` and also I want an alwasy visible Camara icon in menu...

How can I apply my app theme to document provider ?

Comment: Can you able explain what is the exact problem you are facing with

Comment: I am not facing any problem but I I want to know how to customize theme of Image provider

Comment: you want to customize your action bar right ?

Comment: Not my action bar but android Image provider's action bar

Comment: look at the image now I want that camara icon to open camara and also want to apply my apps primary color to android image picker

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html check this,

Comment: *How can I apply my app theme to document provider ?* - you're not trying to change the appearance of the document provider, you're trying to change the appearance of a system app which is the middle  man between the document providers and your app which is requesting a document. This will not work.

Comment: You got my problem correctly. how can I do that

Comment: Just for the record, I tried updating my `styles.xml` to see if I could affect the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` Intent styling when selecting a file but nothing was able to affect it, which makes sense according to what is happening (i.e. it's a completely different application that's native to the OS - our app is just calling it as a Document Provider). The only real solution was to create our own Document Provider via https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/create-document-provider but we've saved that for another day. If anybody has any luck with this, please post.